# How to debug large UIView memory allocation

Tags: ios, debugging, memory, uiview, calayer

I am trying to reduce memory usage in my app, and analysis with Instruments shows that a UIView drawLayer:inContext: is allocating 2.25 MB. I assume the allocation is done right before my code is called, and is due to an incorrect UIView or CALayer size somewhere. But none of my code is involved in the allocation (see picture below), therefore I have no idea how I can debug this. I have already checked all my views and layers, I think, and I do not see anything wrong.

Any ideas are appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Almost everything is in ios UIView, do not worry

Comment: I worry because it allocates a whopping 2.25 MB that is not getting de-allocated anymore. That is most likely contributing heavily to out-of-memory crashes I am getting.

Comment: but that UIViews you use retain? if you retain, you'll need set nil on dealoc (ARC Structure)

Comment: If I knew which UIView it is, I could probably check whether it should be dealloced somewhere. Any idea how I can find out which UIView it is?

Comment: use instruments app (Xcode app), http://goo.gl/jYc20, then you can find all memory leaks, and zombies

Comment: Keep double clicking those bars and it will eventually show you code.

Comment: Well, the screen shot is from Instruments, and it does not show me code, because none of my code is involved.

Comment: Obviously something in your code is causing this.  Framework code doesn't use that much memory.

Comment: Any ideas how I can find out what in my code is causing this?

Comment: Search (cmd+shift+f) for a UIView or caLayer that seems large and active.

Comment: I am afraid you have lost me. How can I search for large UIView's that are active? Do you mean in Instruments, or in XCode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry. The system is allocating a backing store for the layer which happens to be 640 * 960 * 4 bytes.

If you don't leak the layer or view, you'll get your bytes back eventually, at the moment your view is unloaded.

Comment: +1 Exactly -- 2.25MB is almost exactly what's required for a view the size of the screen minus the status bar.

Comment: Mmmm, I guess you're right. I did not think it through enough. I guess it's actually not that big. It means I need to find my problems elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

iOS apps don't just suddenly crash when they run low on memory -- they unload unneeded views and send memory warnings to the view controllers. If your app's crash seems to be related to memory, make sure that you're handling low memory situations properly: implement `-didReceiveMemoryWarning` and `-viewDidUnload` to get rid of data you don't need.

Views can use a lot of memory. `UIViewController` will release its view when it needs to, but if you have another strong/retained pointer to the same view, the functionality that your view controller inherits won't know to release that, and the view will never be deallocated even though it's not needed. It sounds like this may be what's going on in your case, since it's a large block of memory that's about the right size for a full-screen view. Look at your view controllers for additional pointers to your view controller's view (or any other view) and make sure that you set such pointers to nil or release them (depending on whether you're using ARC or not).